# Powershell setting MSolUser's prefered language

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, office365

Stupidly simple script that is meant to get every user in 365 and make sure their preferred language is set to English GB.

```
$soluser = Get-MsolUser

foreach($user in $soluser){
    Set-MsolUser -PreferredLanguage "en-gb"
}
```

The error is "you must provide a required property".

```
$soluser = Get-MsolUser

foreach($user in $soluser){
    $user
}
```

This snippet displays every user in the tenant

Comment: You forgot to tell it to what user it should apply.. `$user | Set-MsolUser  -PreferredLanguage "en-gb"`

Comment: You are correct and I feel rather stupid. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I ran the same code as you and got the same error as below:

```
Connect-MsolService
$soluser = Get-MsolUser

 

foreach($user in $soluser){
    Set-MsolUser -PreferredLanguage "en-gb"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I changed the code like ***Theo*** suggested, I got response successfully like below:

```
Connect-MsolService
$soluser = Get-MsolUser

 

foreach($user in $soluser){
    $user | Set-MsolUser -PreferredLanguage "en-gb"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]